# Prüfer groups are countable

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, set-theory

I have read that for any prime number $p$ the Prüfer $p$-group is countable.

My question is: where can I find a proof of this fact?

Thanks.

Comment: It would probably be a good idea if you told us what definition you are using of these groups.

Comment: i just wrote it.

Comment: You just wrote it *where*? I was suggesting you write it in the body of the question!

Comment: I was considering the Pruffer $p$-group as the abelian group $\langle x_1,x_2\cdots\,:\, px_1=0,\, px_{i+1}=x_i \rangle$ But @rschwieb already pointed me that they are all subsets of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is can be viewed as a subset of the group $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, which is obviously countable.

The subset representing the Prüfer group is just the set of all elements with order a power of $p$.

Comment: Thanks.
Now i see that it was an easy question, my problem is that i was watching those groups in the form $\langle x_1,x_2\cdots\, :\, x_{i+1}^p=x_i, x_1^p=1 \rangle.$ I have had forgotten the characterization you wrote.

Comment: Countably presented groups are countable: this is independent of anything. They are quotients of countably generated free groups, and it is easy to see these are countable.